# JAVA SWT with easy eclipse

Tags: java, swt

I want to develop one dialog box with labels,textboxes and buttons which will take input and do validation. So the main problem is that while setting any layout i am not getting my desired position of widgets and if i set the layout to null then the widgets are not visible only.

Can some body help me out.

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to learn API is to look for working examples and start modifying them to suit your needs. A good library of SWT examples is located here:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Here is an article on understanding SWT layouts:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try if any anchoring option is there in java as in C#.